# JHipster JDL not generating anything because the database type must be passed

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I'm using Jhipster 4.5.3 to generate some code from a JDL file I've created. Because I couldn't generate anything, I took the [JDL Blog sample](https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/master/blog.jh)... and I have the same issues.

The [JDL documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/) still mentions :

> You can generate entities from a JDL file by running jhipster import-jdl your-jdl-file.jh

But when I do that I get :

> The jdl is being parsed.
>   { name: 'NullPointerException',
>     message: 'The parsed JDL content and the database type must be passed.',

Looking [at the code](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/master/lib/parser/jdl_parser.js#L36), it looks like we have to pass a new parameter, the database type (this is not mentioned in the doc BTW). [Looking at the code again](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/blob/master/lib/core/jhipster/database_types.js#L7), there are quite a few database types to choose from. But any database I choose, I get

> Error: 
>   Could not find postgresql, make sure the path is correct!

```
at Environment.error (/Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:89:38)
at jdlFiles.forEach (/Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:42:34)
at Array.forEach (native)
at constructor.validate (/Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:40:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:417:23)
at /Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at /Users/agoncal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:9
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I need to execute a yo jhipster first, and then import the JDL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you generate an app with 'yo jhipster' first ? Can you post the generated .yo-rc.json ?

Comment: Ah, no, I didn't. I thought importing the JDL would generate everything. It does work after executing a yo jhipster. Thanks

Comment: It seems the doc is unclear. Would you PR to improve it ?

Comment: Done : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io/compare/master...agoncal:patch-1